# angular readAsDataUrl is not giving the correct result when combined with jcorp plugin

Tags: angularjs

I have written a directive to use the plug in like this

```
app.directive("ngImageSelect",function(){
    return {
        link: function($scope,el){

            $(el).Jcrop({
                onChange:   showCoords,
                onSelect:   showCoords,
                onRelease:  clearCoords
            },function(){
                jcrop_api = this;
            }); 
            function showCoords(data){
                $('#x1').val(data.x);
                $('#y1').val(data.y);
                $('#x2').val(data.x2);
                $('#y2').val(data.y2);
                $('#width').val(data.w);
                $('#height').val(data.h);
            }
            function clearCoords(){
                $('#coords input').val('');
            }      
        }
    }
});
```

the problem with this is , when we browse image first time it previews correctly, If we try to change the image, it is not changing, still it loads old image.PLease help me.

Comment: Can you brief on your problem a bit more?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/zHGttnGkhV6y4cxO7aCs?p=preview       this is the link for demo . Please try to browse an image and then try to browse a different image it is still showing old image